# open an excel file from outlook vsto Addin with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, excel-interop

how do you open/work on excel files using an outlook addin?

I import the outlook namespace:

```
Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
```

But the excel namespace is not accessible

```
Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel
```

I can only import `Microsoft.Office.tools.excel`, but it doesn't provide the functionality I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

you need to add a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel extension via:

> Project > Add reference > Extension > Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel

Then you can:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


    Public Class ThisAddIn

        Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

    end class
```